# Is there a mechanism to send keystrokes to a powershell process?

Tags: powershell

I have a CLI that must be interacted with to some extent. I start it, check what it has output and, depending on what it has output, send 'ENTER'.

This is already fairly complex to set up in powershell on here. Starting with what I am using,

```
$processStartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$processStartInfo.FileName = "theCli.exe"
$processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($processStartInfo)
```

And, after some time:

```
$output = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$matched = $output -match $pattern

if ($matched){
  # Send Key: Enter
}
```

I figure there has to be a way to do this, even if I have to inject a large C# type. The one alternative I've seen is to start up a shell, and use Windows Forms to send keys to the window under focus (the other shell).  This is not good because the user will be someone other than me, and they'll be gaming -- so if I can't do this without screwing around w/ windows forms, I am going to find some other way to get the information than the CLI. Or, we'll have to change the CLI.

The question amounts to: although this might be hard or tough, is there any way to push a few key strokes to a powershell subprocess with no windows form hosting it? Better yet, is there a way to push it to a `[System.Diagnostics.Process]`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with a *console* application, you should provide input to it via its *stdin* (standard input) stream instead of trying to simulate interactive user input.

While conditionally sending stdin input while the program is running in response to stdout output received so far is non-trivial, a pragmatic solution may be to send the stdin input *unconditionally*, and rely on it to be *ignored* if not needed.

The following examples illustrate this:

```bash
# Effectively send ENTER (a newline) via stdin to respond to the `pause` prompt.
'' | cmd /c pause

# Do the same for a command that *doesn't* read from stdin, relying on it
# to be ignored.
'' | cmd /c ver
```